With MySql is there any way to create a global endless sequence integer, other than the trick of using a "replace" table?
In most systems you need a global, endlessly increasing sequence number. With MySql the only way I know to do it is, make a new small table for the purpose:
mysql>  CREATE TABLE `ubersequence` (
    ->  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->  `unused` varchar(32) not null unique,
    ->  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into ubersequence (unused) values ('snap');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from ubersequence ;
+----+--------+
| id | unused |
+----+--------+
|  1 | snap   |
+----+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Every time you need the next value, just replace in to it and then read the new id.
mysql> replace into ubersequence (unused) values ('snap') ;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from ubersequence ;
+----+--------+
| id | unused |
+----+--------+
|  2 | snap   |
+----+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> replace into ubersequence (unused) values ('snap') ;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from ubersequence ;
+----+--------+
| id | unused |
+----+--------+
|  3 | snap   |
+----+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Don't do this more than two billion times!
(Of course, those two steps and likely more will have to be atomic transaction in your code.)
In short, is there a way in MySql I don't know about, other than using a utility table as above, to get a global increasing seq?
(By global I mean database-wide. But indeed if it was installation wide that would obviously be equally as good and work the same.)
Purely FTR I use
/home/ubuntu/main# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

typically on Ubuntu, just in case it matters.

PS, of course within one table it will indeed within the table increment the the id for you if using the "replace" technique; my question is about, as I say, database-wide (or even myssql install wide would be fine).

I don't think there's anything like that. Do other databases have something like this?

? @Barmar sure, it's common in oracle etc.  and used a a general principle in basically all modern client-server sync systems, etc  :O

I'm aware of IDENTITY, but I thought it was also tied to a particular table like AUTO_INCREMENT.

I guess this is sort of a duplicate, but all the answers over there are a mess. Strange!  Well you have answered the question by explicitly telling me there's nothing like that in MySql.  Such is life.

@Barmar, Sequence objects are supported by, for example, DB2, MariaDB, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and SQL Server. Not supported in BigQuery, MySQL, or SQLite.

@BillKarwin ah! thank you so much!  I'm so silly. I was of course thinking of Postgres, face palm.  Thank you
